Pandas create % and # distribution list in descending order for each group
I have a pandas dataframe like as below
data = {
    'cust_id': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc'],
    'product_id': [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
    'purchase_country': ['India', 'India', 'India', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

My objective is to do the below for each group of cust_id and product_id
a) create two output columns - 'pct_region_split' and 'num_region_split'
b) For 'pct_region_split' - store the % of country split. For ex: For the specific group shown in sample data, Australia - 70% (7 out of 10 is 70%) and India - 30% (3 out of 10 is 30%)
c) For 'num_region_split' - just store the no of rows for country value. For ex: For the specific group shown in sample data, Australia - 7 rows out of total 10 and India is 3 out of total 10.
b) Store the values in a list format (descending order). Meaning, Australia should appear first because it has 70% as the value (which is higher than India).
I tried the below but it is going no where
df['total_purchases'] = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'])['purchase_country'].transform('size')
df['unique_country'] = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'])['purchase_country'].transform('nunique')

Please do note that my real data has more than 1000 customers and 200 product combinations.
I expect my output in a new dataframe like as shown below for each cust and product_id combination


Out of curiosity, what made you decide to pick the other solution? It has many more steps, uses the inefficient iterrows.

The steps were to explain the process and to provide the output as expected (column order, sort, percentage sign). But I agree that for very large datasets vectorized operations can be more efficient.

I mainly chose the lengthy one due to its explanation which was easy for me to follow. Of course, I do understand that your code is short just few lines but was lacking explanation. However, as @keithwalsh also feels your code is better for larger dataset, I marked your solution now.

Use a custom function and groupby.apply:
def f(g):
    s = g['purchase_country'].value_counts()
    return pd.Series({'num_region_split': ', '.join(s.index+':'+s.astype('str')),
                      'pct_region_split': ', '.join(s.index+':'+s.div(s.sum()).astype('str')),
                     })

df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'], as_index=False).apply(f)

Output:
  cust_id  product_id      num_region_split          pct_region_split
0     abc          12  Australia:7, India:3  Australia:0.7, India:0.3


Your original code:
df['total_purchases'] = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'])['purchase_country'].transform('size')
df['unique_country'] = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'])['purchase_country'].transform('nunique')

It only gives total purchases and the number of unique countries, but not individual counts or percentages for each country within each group.
The below gives the output you need:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'cust_id': ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc'],
    'product_id': [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
    'purchase_country': ['India', 'India', 'India', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia', 'Australia']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

country_counts = df.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id', 'purchase_country']).size().reset_index(name='count')

country_counts['total_purchases'] = country_counts.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id'])['count'].transform('sum')

country_counts['pct'] = (country_counts['count'] / country_counts['total_purchases'] * 100).round().astype(int)

country_counts = country_counts.sort_values(['cust_id', 'product_id', 'pct'], ascending=[True, True, False])

def aggregate_splits(group):
    pct_split = ', '.join([f"{row['purchase_country']}:{row['pct']}%" for _, row in group.iterrows()])
    num_split = ', '.join([f"{row['purchase_country']}:{row['count']}" for _, row in group.iterrows()])
    return pd.Series({'pct_region_split': pct_split, 'num_region_split': num_split})

split_df = country_counts.groupby(['cust_id', 'product_id']).apply(aggregate_splits).reset_index()

final_df = split_df[['cust_id', 'product_id', 'pct_region_split', 'num_region_split']]

print(final_df)

Output:




cust_id
product_id
pct_region_split
num_region_split




0
abc
12
Australia:70%, India:30%
Australia:7, India:3




Count the number of purchases each country has for each customer and product
Compute total purchases for each group so as to calculate percentages
Find out what percentage each country's purchases are of the total
Sort countries from highest to lowest percentage
Create the 'pct_region_split' and 'num_region_split' strings
Create final dataframe

